# Adding a serial number into a worksheet sheet1 with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, serial-number

I have a sheet1 with
Like this:

```txt
     ColumnA     ColumnB
1    SerialNo.   Smartphones
2                iphone 15
3                iphone 15 pro
4                iphone 15 plus
5                iphone 15 pro max


So I came up with this code that puts a rows count into ColumnA whenever I put a smartphone name in ColumnB

Private Sub 
 Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim count As Long

count=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("B:B")

For i = 1 to count
Sheet1.Range("A" & i + 1).Value = i
Next i
End sub

But here it does only if I enter something in columnB ,

Is it possible if I enter something in like any column of this selected sheet ,that put a rowcounts in the ColumnA
?
```

I tried various functions related to the serial number from this site and from others too , but didn't found anything which can put a serial no. If u write something in the smartphones column.

Can anyone know it how to put a serial number automatically,  with the VBA code?

Comment: Look into the `worksheet_change` event.  Plenty of examples of that here on SO.

Comment: It's unclear where the SerialNo. value is coming from. Is there a table?

Comment: Exactly  where in the worksheet_change? Like here in stackoverflow?

Comment: No that r just the rows , the serial no column is empty, so serial number has to be given with s vba code

Comment: What kind of serial numbers? If you have a code that will fill the empty cells with the serial numbers, share it and we'll help you automate it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So when a new smart phone is added it should automatically include the serial number - how does VBA know the serial number?  It can't look at the barcode on the phone packaging, it can't look at the settings on the phone..... basically what other comments have said - how will it know the serial number?

Comment: Hi! to everyone and sorry to all for the late reply! So basically if I add a smartphone name into ColumnB it should put a serial number(and by serial number I mean rowcount) automatically in the columnA im sorry if I couldn't explain my questions that clearly.

Comment: Okay I got that too , I put the Z in the range and got the wide range from cell  b to z , but how to stop increasing the rowcounts if I put a value into a same row, what condition should I put in?